# After completing npm audit fix, git status shows a bunch of modified/deleted node_modules files. How can I ignore them or delete?

Tags: node.js, git, express, git-bash, gitignore

I tried adding node_modules/ to my .gitignore, but that didn't work.
This is a small snippet of what I'm seeing:

$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add/rm ..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git restore ..." to discard changes in working directory)
modified:   .gitignore
modified:   node_modules/.bin/acorn
modified:   node_modules/.bin/acorn.cmd
deleted:    node_modules/.bin/babylon
deleted:    node_modules/.bin/babylon.cmd
modified:   node_modules/.bin/concurrently
modified:   node_modules/.bin/concurrently.cmd
modified:   node_modules/.bin/mime
modified:   node_modules/.bin/mime.cmd
modified:   node_modules/.bin/semver
modified:   node_modules/.bin/semver.cmd
modified:   node_modules/.bin/tree-kill
modified:   node_modules/.bin/tree-kill.cmd
deleted:    node_modules/.bin/uglifyjs
deleted:    node_modules/.bin/uglifyjs.cmd
deleted:    node_modules/.bin/which
deleted:    node_modules/.bin/which.cmd
deleted:    node_modules/@types/babel-types/LICENSE
deleted:    node_modules/@types/babel-types/README.md
deleted:    node_modules/@types/babel-types/index.d.ts
deleted:    node_modules/@types/babel-types/package.json
deleted:    node_modules/@types/babylon/LICENSE
deleted:    node_modules/@types/babylon/README.md
deleted:    node_modules/@types/babylon/index.d.ts
deleted:    node_modules/@types/babylon/package.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the output, It seems like the files under node_modules directory was already been tracked by git.

You also need to remove node_modules folder from git tracking

`git rm -r --cached node_modules/`

git will still show changes (deleted changes) for node_modules/ directory , as those files are now removed from git history

make a commit, from next time files under that directory will not be monitored

Comment: Thank you so much! That did the trick. I'm not sure why my node_modules were already being tracked without me doing it. I guess I'll have to investigate that issue later.